# named anchor not working webview android

Tags: android

In my little app i have a webview, i only have one html file in the assets folder. I'm trying to use a named anchor to make a Jump Link but it doesn't work. It only says **Web page not available** I don't know where i'm wrong. Is it trying to load a html file with the name tag i provided?

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/topics.html");
```

**EDIT:**

here's my html

```
<html>
<body>

<a href=”#tip”>Go somewhere</a>

//a lot of  <br/>...

Somewhere

<a name=”tip”></a>

</body>
</html>
```

And yes the topics.html is under assets/

Comment: check this post also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188348/android-html-anchor-link-works-only-once-in-webview/11205345#11205345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does your program fail - with the loading or when you click the anchor? It sounds like the problem is with your HTML file, so you should probably show the code from that instead. :) Also, the full LogCat output is handy too. The more info the merrier.

I recently implemented a WebView, the HTML code is extremely straight-forward (since I know close to no HTML and just wanted an easy way to display documentation). A simple anchor is just this for example:

```
<a href="#q1">Navigating the application</a>

...

<a name="q1"></a> 
<p><b>Navigating the application</b></p> 
<p>...sliding motion (to the left or to the right) with your finger...</p>
```

If your program is failing at the actual loading part, then ensure that you have placed the topics.html file correctly in the /assets/ folder in your project folder. It has to be at the very root of your project folder - ie. `workspace\<projectname>\assets\topics.html`

Your code for loading the webpage looks fine.

Comment: this is embarazing, i got the wrong quotation marks. I had this `”` instead of this: `"` which should probably mean that the encoding is wrong. As the matter of fact i didn't even had the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` because i was testing. But anyways, now is working. Thanks for the help

Comment: @madcoderz Oh man, that can be annoying. I would probably not have spotted that from your code above since it's such an easy thing to miss. Good thing you got it fixed!