# Android : Html Anchor Link works only once in webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am facing some strange issue in webview at time of loading html content with anchor link.
Following code works perfect for anchor tag but **only once**.
Second time when i press anchor tag it is **not working.**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mywebview);

        String html = "<html><body><p><a href='#C4'>See also Chapter 4</a></p><p><h2>Chapter 1</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 2</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 3</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2><a name='C4'>Chapter 4</a></h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 5</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 6</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 7</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 8</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 9</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p></body></html>";
        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";

        WebView myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);

    }
```

i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039555/android-webview-anchor-link-jump-link-not-working) link but not worked for me.

**UPDATE:**

**Testing result of my code in various device.**

**Working**
 1. Samsung S Plus --> 2.3.4
 2. Samsung Galaxy Y --> 2.3.6
 3. Samsung Galaxy Tab --> 2.3.3
 4. Motorola Xoom --> 3.2

**Not Working**
 1. LG Optimus --> 2.2
 2. DELL XCD35(ZTE Blade) --> 2.2
 3. HTC WildFire --> 2.2.1

Is this OS issue or something else? Any Solution for this??

---

Comment: All @DownVoters can you explain reason for down voting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was to Reload the Page again after Anchor link Click.

I have used the following code,

chapters.xml in Assets folder

```
<html>
<body>
<p><a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4</a></p>
<p><h2><a name='C1'>Chapter 1<a></h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
<h2>Chapter 2</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
<h2>Chapter 3</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
<h2><a name='C4'>Chapter 4</a></h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
<h2>Chapter 5</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
<h2>Chapter 6</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
<h2>Chapter 7</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
<a href="#C1">See also Chapter 1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVA code : First Way**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myWebView = new WebView(this);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chapters.html");

        setContentView(myWebView);

        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
                new MyGestureDetector());
        View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        myWebView.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            myWebView.reload();
            Log.i("", "Reload");
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT JAVA CODE : Second Way** - I have tried this thing insted `onTouchListener` and that working fine for me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView myWebView;
    public static boolean flag = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myWebView = new WebView(this);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chapters.html");
        setContentView(myWebView);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains("#") && flag == false) {
                    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**To Open Another HTML File's Anchor Tag from One file**

```
        myWebView = new WebView(this);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.htm");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                try{
                chapter = url.substring(url.indexOf("#"),url.length());
                url = url.substring(0,url.indexOf("#"));
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    chapter = "";
                }
                myWebView.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (!chapter.equalsIgnoreCase("") && flag == false) {
                    myWebView.loadUrl(url+chapter);
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        });
        setContentView(myWebView);
```

Comment: Don't seems to be a feasible solution. Because user might have to touch anywhere in the webview so it will reload webview everytime.

Comment: Now check the updated answer, Reload done only when user taps. And if you still not satisfied with output..you can surely remove green check mark..so other user can know that you are still looking for better ans, I will not mind it..I will also continue trying :)

Comment: Using your flag variable, I just managed to solve a problem in 4.1.1, when the page was refreshing continually around the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this code . It works fine .

```
   String html = "<html><body><p><a href='#C4'>See also Chapter 4</a></p><p><h2>Chapter 1</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 2</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 3</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2><a name='C4'>Chapter 4</a></h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 5</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 6</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 7</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 8</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p><h2>Chapter 9</h2><p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p></body></html>";
    String mime = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";

    final WebView myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("app:html", html, mime, encoding, null);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
    {  
       @Override  
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
       {
           super.onPageFinished(view, "app:html");
           view.loadDataWithBaseURL("app:html", html, mime, encoding, null);
       }  
    });
```

Comment: +1 for the very good Attempt but Using your code, Testing in emulator sometimes works and again stops after 2-3 clicks again starts working and in HTC device doesn't work at all, Tell me if my testing is wrong.

Comment: @Chirag Raval it works. Thanks.. but sometimes needs to click on link twice or more.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens on Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 devices: If you have a mobile web page (either in assets or loaded from the web) whose contents fill across the whole screen width, then some links like this:

```
<a href=... HTML links
```

...will not work! They will just fail to load the next page! It's a bit strange.

The bug is documented here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=929

Even though it was logged in 2009, it does still happen on Android 4.0.3/4.0.4 devices.

The solution is to not use:

`android:layout_height="wrap_content` on the WebView.

Replace it with:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple 2-liner javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
      function jump_top() {
          location.href = "#top";
          location.hash = "";
      }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a name="top"></a>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
...
<br />Now you are at the bottom of the page
<br />
<a onclick="jump_top()">To Top</a>
</body>
</html>
```