# webview links not working

Tags: android, webview, click, hyperlink, response

l am using webview in my xml, loading html file from asset directory. But clicking on links sometimes launching browser on first click and sometimes not responding even after 5 clicks.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please input some code that you have used.It would make things much more clear.

Comment: mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/FAQsAndHelp.html");  FAQsAndHelp.html file is html file in assests directory to load.  No extra code is written. xml file has a linearlayout as root and a webview the only child.

Comment: Check for this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15162998/2116185

Answer (score 5):

For, this you've to use [WebViewClient()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#WebViewClient%28%29) to your `WebView`

```
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
.....
.....   // Your stuff
.....
web.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    public HelloWebViewClient()
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Spk.. i had already tried this but call sometimes came to shouldoverrideurlloading method..and mostly not...

Comment: clicking on link is working fine...but touching near by link makes it selectable but not calling shouldoverrideurlloading...

Answer (score 4):

just add these lines

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```