# Override webview to not load choosing screen

Tags: android, webview, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to load the google maps direction link to a webview inside the app. But when i load them it forces me to choose with what app it should open the direction.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
String url = String.format("http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", getIntent().getDoubleExtra("start_lat", 0),
             getIntent().getDoubleExtra("start_lng", 0),
             getIntent().getDoubleExtra("end_lat", 0),
             getIntent().getDoubleExtra("end_lng", 0));
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

This forces me to choose if i want to open with google maps or with the phone browser app. I want to let the app to load the direction url in my app, not an external app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,java.lang.String%29)

And override the loading of the URL to continue loading it within the webview.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement webviewclient and
override the url loading

check this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11859770/3518278