# Detect a click on <a> tag from HTML data?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am having some html code which i am displaying in Webview, it has a read more link in it on click of which it takes me to default browser. But i want to change this behavior and open that link in different activity, for which i want to detect the click on that link within the HTML code. I tried the following code but to no avail.

Inside onCreate 
registerForContextMenu(w);

and after that

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    WebView.HitTestResult result = w.getHitTestResult();

    System.out.println("asdasfdf");

    if (result.getType() == HitTestResult.ANCHOR_TYPE
            || result.getType() == HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

        System.out.println("#%@#%$%");
        // set the header title to the link url
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188348/android-html-anchor-link-works-only-once-in-webview/11205345#11205345 Read this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method of `WebViewClient` will do the trick.

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
  @Override  
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
    // Load the url in your own webView. or pass the url to another activity. and stop the current loading. check the following pages
  }
}
```

You'll get the clicked url in second parameter.

Check this link for more detail.

[WebViewClient (shouldOverrideUrlLoading)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

http://www.catchingtales.com/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-and-redirect/416/